# How to set k-Means clustering labels from highest to lowest with Python?

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a dataset of 38 apartments and their electricity consumption in the morning, afternoon and evening. I am trying to clusterize this dataset using the k-Means implementation from scikit-learn, and am getting some interesting results.

First clustering results:
[image: Img]

This is all very well, and with 4 clusters I obviously get 4 labels associated to each apartment - 0, 1, 2 and 3. Using the `random_state` parameter of `KMeans` method, I can fix the seed in which the centroids are randomly initialized, so consistently I get the same labels attributed to the same apartments.

However, as this specific case is in regards of energy consumption, a measurable classification between the highest and the lowest consumers can be performed. I would like, thus, to assign the label 0 to the apartments with lowest consumption level, label 1 to apartments that consume a bit more and so on.

As of now, my labels are [2 1 3 0], or ["black", "green", "blue", "red"]; I would like them to be [0 1 2 3] or ["red", "green", "black", "blue"]. How should I proceed to do so, while still keeping the centroid initialization random (with fixed seed)?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I think your best bet is to annotate the labels after.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Transforming the labels through a **lookup table** is a straightforward way to achieve what you want.

To begin with I generate some mock data:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1000)

n = 38
X_morning = np.random.uniform(low=.02, high=.18, size=38)
X_afternoon = np.random.uniform(low=.05, high=.20, size=38)
X_night = np.random.uniform(low=.025, high=.175, size=38)
X = np.vstack([X_morning, X_afternoon, X_night]).T
```

Then I perform clustering on data:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
k = 4
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=0).fit(X)
```

And finally I use NumPy's [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to create a lookup table like this:

```
idx = np.argsort(kmeans.cluster_centers_.sum(axis=1))
lut = np.zeros_like(idx)
lut[idx] = np.arange(k)
```

## Sample run:

```
In [70]: kmeans.cluster_centers_.sum(axis=1)
Out[70]: array([ 0.3214523 ,  0.40877735,  0.26911353,  0.25234873])

In [71]: idx
Out[71]: array([3, 2, 0, 1], dtype=int64)

In [72]: lut
Out[72]: array([2, 3, 1, 0], dtype=int64)

In [73]: kmeans.labels_
Out[73]: array([1, 3, 1, ..., 0, 1, 0])

In [74]: lut[kmeans.labels_]
Out[74]: array([3, 0, 3, ..., 2, 3, 2], dtype=int64)
```

`idx` shows the cluster center labels ordered from lowest to highest consumption level. The appartments for which `lut[kmeans.labels_]` is `0` / `3` belong to the cluster with the lowest / highest consumption levels.

Comment: I was looking for something built in in the scikit learn package, wondering if it was already implemented in the clustering methods. Not having that, your solution worked perfectly - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sort the centroids based on their **vector magnitude** is better, since you can use it to predict other data using the same model. Here is my implementation in [my repo](https://github.com/yasirroni/sorted_cluster)

```py
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

def sorted_cluster(x, model=None):
    if model == None:
        model = KMeans()
    model = sorted_cluster_centers_(model, x)
    model = sorted_labels_(model, x)
    return model

def sorted_cluster_centers_(model, x):
    model.fit(x)
    new_centroids = []
    magnitude = []
    for center in model.cluster_centers_:
        magnitude.append(np.sqrt(center.dot(center)))
    idx_argsort = np.argsort(magnitude)
    model.cluster_centers_ = model.cluster_centers_[idx_argsort]
    return model

def sorted_labels_(sorted_model, x):
    sorted_model.labels_ = sorted_model.predict(x)
    return sorted_model
```

Example:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.vstack([
    100 + np.random.random((2,3)),
    np.random.random((2,3)),
    5 + np.random.random((3,3)),
    10 + np.random.random((2,3))
])
print('Data:')
print(arr)

cluster = KMeans(n_clusters=4)

print('\n Without sort:')
cluster.fit(arr)
print(cluster.cluster_centers_)
print(cluster.labels_)
print(cluster.predict([[5,5,5],[1,1,1]]))

print('\n With sort:')
cluster = sorted_cluster(arr, cluster)
print(cluster.cluster_centers_)
print(cluster.labels_)
print(cluster.predict([[5,5,5],[1,1,1]]))
```

Output:

```
Data:
[[100.52656263 100.57376566 100.63087757]
 [100.70144046 100.94095196 100.57095386]
 [  0.21284187   0.75623797   0.77349013]
 [  0.28241023   0.89878796   0.27965047]
 [  5.14328748   5.37025887   5.26064209]
 [  5.21030632   5.09597417   5.29507699]
 [  5.81531591   5.11629056   5.78542656]
 [ 10.25686526  10.64181304  10.45651994]
 [ 10.14153211  10.28765705  10.20653228]]

 Without sort:
[[ 10.19919868  10.46473505  10.33152611]
 [100.61400155 100.75735881 100.60091572]
 [  0.24762605   0.82751296   0.5265703 ]
 [  5.38963657   5.19417453   5.44704855]]
[1 1 2 2 3 3 3 0 0]
[3 2]

 With sort:
[[  0.24762605   0.82751296   0.5265703 ]
 [  5.38963657   5.19417453   5.44704855]
 [ 10.19919868  10.46473505  10.33152611]
 [100.61400155 100.75735881 100.60091572]]
[3 3 0 0 1 1 1 2 2]
[1 0]
```